# Tooltips getting cutoff in pie charts in highcharts

Tags: jquery-plugins, highcharts

I have a pie chart which is being generated from a json string. The pie is getting created correctly but what is happening is the tooltip is getting cutoff when the text to be displayed in the tooltip is large. I have tried increasing the width and height of the svg area. But the charts are generated dynamically so i have no way of setting the chart widht and height dynamically depending on the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can adjust the margins `margin:[0,100,0,100],` to shrink the pie chart so that the tooltips/labels will appear. This has been set to automatically scale the chart in Highcharts 3.0.

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released

http://github.highcharts.com/v3.0Beta/highcharts.js

http://jsfiddle.net/Zvrt6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Increase Height and width of your chart div or put your code in jsfiddle if possible, so that we can get more idea

Answer (score 0):

This example could be relevant to your situation- http://jsfiddle.net/4ac8b/1/. When you re-size the result pane you will notice the chart size changes accordingly.

You will need to set the size of your container so that the chart is drawn in that area itself. http://jsfiddle.net/4ac8b/. Even when you re-size the result pane the chart size wont change.

Answer (score 0):

Change the diameter of your pie chart to allow additional information

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-pie--size